# Does the port support display?

Tags: display, external-display, asus-laptop

I have a port in my laptop (Asus UX430U). I have not used it ever. I am wondering if i could use it to have a second display?

It is the rightmost port on the left hand side:

[image: https://ibb.co/SR5DtWX]

Comment: -1 from me because you haven't done any research before asking. This question is trivially answered by checking the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Does the port support display?

Yes.

That port is a USB Type-C/DisplayPort combo port.

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> The USB (Universal Serial Bus) Type-C port provides a transfer rate of up to 5 Gbit/s and is backward compatible to USB 2.0. Use a USB Type-C adapter to connect your Notebook PC to an external display.

Source [Asus UX430U User Manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/UX430UA/0409_E12021_UX430_UX530_A.pdf) (pdf)